# Algorithm to check matching letters in an array (before, after, cross)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I have an array of letter like so

```
var letters  = 
     ["Y", "X", "A", 
      "Y", "O", "H", 
      "A", "O", "O"];
```

I've created a loop that checks if the letter before the current is the same and the letter after the current is the same.

```
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  var currentLetter = i;
  var before = i - 1;
  var after = i + 1;

  if (letters[after] == letters[currentLetter]) {
    console.log("Array Position " + currentLetter + ": " + letters[currentLetter] + ' matches after');
  }
  if (letters[before] == letters[currentLetter]) {
    console.log("Array Position " + currentLetter + ": " + letters[currentLetter] + ' matches before');
  }
```

I'm having difficulty on how to right the logic to check if the letter across is the same ( obviously there is no cross since its one dimensional). But is there a pattern that i'm missing.  How would I write this without hardcoding the algorithm for each block?

Example:

> letter[0] should check: letter[1], letter[3], letter[4]
>   letter[1] should check letter [0], [2], [3], [5]
>   etc..

Comment: Take your array, decide on how long is each row (in this specific case it's 3) now in the loop when you check your index you need to know where it is located inside of the row so what you do is `index % rowLength` now you check next row + index of element in the row (and continue + row + index of element in the row) and doing the same to the other across , and also checking the minus row and minus the element index. hope I was clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this fiddle for you, I believe it is close enough I it's not covering all of the weird possible cases I guess but it's enough for you to work with:http://jsfiddle.net/0mja7zrr/4/

```
    var letters1  = 
         ["Y", "X", "A", 
          "Y", "O", "H", 
          "A", "O", "O"];

    var letters2  = 
         ["Y", "X", "A", 
          "Y", "Y", "H", 
          "A", "O", "Y"];

    function checkAcross(index, rowLength, letters){
        var indexInRow = index % rowLength;
        var rowNum = Math.floor(index / rowLength);
        var totalRows = Math.floor(letters.length/rowLength);
        var letterToCheck = letters[index];
        var delta = 0;
        //checking
        for(var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++){
            delta = Math.abs(rowNum - i); //delta between rows and elements
            var firstElementOfRow = rowLength * i; //get the index of first element
            if(firstElementOfRow >= index){
                if(letterToCheck != letters[firstElementOfRow + indexInRow + delta]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(letterToCheck != letters[firstElementOfRow +indexInRow - delta]){
                    return false;
                }
            }                           
        }
    return true;
}

console.log(checkAcross(4,3,letters1));
console.log(checkAcross(4,3,letters2));
```

Comment: That makes sense breaking it down into rows thank you so  for writing this! should be enough for me to continue